# Listing directory on vsftpd server with FileZilla fails with "The data connection could not be established: ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt timed out"

Tags: centos, ftp, vsftpd

I am trying to setup vsftpd on my server, it works, runs and connects. But when trying to connect to the server with FileZilla, I get the following error:

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/var/www/html"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (193,23,181,154,235,226).
Command:    LIST
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ETIMEDOUT - Connection 
attempt timed out
```

I already set ports and forewarded them into the firewall:

vsftpd.conf:

```
connect_from_port_20 = YES
pasv_enable = YES
pasv_addr_resolve = NO
pasv_address = 193.23.181.154
pasv_min_port = 4242
pasv_max_port = 4243
port_enable = YES
```

[Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSmVQ.jpg)

What am I doing wrong / do I need to add?

Comment: Only two pasv_ports? Why not forward a larger range, like at least 10 or 16 ports?

Answer (score 0):

Your vsftpd configuration is not applied. Maybe you didn't restart the server after changing the configuration?

```
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (193,23,181,154,235,226).
```

This means that the server is listening on port 60386 (235 << 8 + 226). I.e. not on a port in range 4242-4243.